# htaccess Redirect page

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to do a redirect (->) in de .htaccess-file, the following way? :

```
www.website.com/home -> www.website.com/somepage/home
www.website.com/contact -> www.website.com/somepage/contact
www.website.com/blog -> www.website.com/somepage/blog
```

Thanks in advance,

Aäron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(home|contact|blog)/?$ somepage/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is it possible to make home, contact variable?

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you pls give more details what you want to do?